# How to calculate the direct product of Latin squares

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, latin-square

In the example below a 2x2 Latin square is multiplied by a 3x3 Latin square which gives a 6x6 Latin square. My question is what it the method for multiplying these two different sized Latin squares together, how do you arrive at the 6x6 Latin Square and where does each number come from?

1 2

2 1

2x2 Latin square

X

3x3 Latin square

1 2 3

2 3 1

3 1 2

=

1 2 3 4 5 6

2 1 4 3 6 5

3 4 5 6 1 2

4 3 6 5 2 1

5 6 1 2 3 4

6 5 2 1 4 3

Comment: There is a thing called the Kronecker product, which works similarly as for matrices. However, this doesn't yield the kind of product you wrote down. What is your source?

Comment: I found this example in ‘Combinatorics: Topics, Techniques, Algorithms’ by Peter J. Cameron

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the book, this is the result of identifying Latin squares with quasigroups; this operation then corresponds to the direct product of quasigroups. In this example, let's say we have quasigroups $G = \{g_1,g_2\}$ and $H = \{h_1,h_2,h_3\}$ with multiplication tables given by those two matrices. Then the direct product $$G \times H = \{ (g_1,h_1),(g_2,h_1),(g_1,h_2), (g_2,h_2), (g_1,h_3), (g_2,h_3)\}$$ may be identified with the set $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ (this ordering is arbitrary but important; I'm using the one the author picked). Then for example, the element in the fourth line and third column in the product square is given by the product $(g_2,h_2)(g_1,h_2) = (g_2g_1,h_2h_2) = (g_2,h_3)$, which corresponds to the label $6$.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but what about line four column two, using your method I get a 5 out instead of a 3, so where am I going wrong?

Comment: @Lsquare Oops, you are quite right. I think I had the order wrong; this one seems to work.

Comment: I’ve spent some time using what you have said, but I am now more confused, I can’t see why you have used (g2,h1) & (g1,h3) for the fourth row and third column respectively.

Comment: @Lsquare I had edited the ordering but not the example below; everything should be fine now.

Comment: My last question is how does h2h2 = h3?

Comment: @Lsquare Because the $3 \times 3$ matrix corresponds to the quasigroup operation in $H$. Therefore to compute $h_2h_2$, we look at the second line, second column in that matrix, which has label $3$ and hence corresponds to $h_3$.